# plone portlet ajax update machinery

Tags: jquery, plone

I am working on a plone portlet which provides some user interface to change parameters which reflect in different portlet display, similar to the calendar portlet. I.e. the portlet provides links to update the portlet content displayed.

The plone developer manual http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/client-side-functionality-javascript/kss states that the use of kss is deprecated.

> KSS was Plones standard mechanism for binding behaviors to document nodes, but it is being gradually replaced with jQuery. As of Plone 4.1, KSS is deprecated. Please do not create new KSS-dependent functionality. Make plans to replace existing functionality.

In plone.portlets README.txt is nice information about the functionality of the portlet infrastructure, regarding portlet managmenent, assignement and such (thanks, I think its from optilude!).

In plone.app.portlets is the related code for the calendar-portlet, which I thought could give me some advice for the portlet i develop. The generated portlet-html containes a hash-value with a portlet-related dict encoded, which the server-machinery uses when an ajax request comes in. But how is the process of "registering" my own portlet to take part on that nice part of plones provided infrastructure?

In plone.app.kss is a file called calendar.py,

```
# --
# Calendar in-place refreshment
# --

implements(IPloneKSSView)

@kssaction
def refreshCalendar(self, month, year, portlethash):
    'In-place refreshment of the calendar.'
    month, year = int(month), int(year)
    self.getCommandSet('plone').refreshPortlet(portlethash, year=year, month=month)
```

Intimidated by the statement from the dev manual I have to decide the following:

Should I go with a the kss-way to update  my portlet? If so, how do I tell the plone machinery my parameter set for update? I know to put the parameters into the `href` tag of the link, but how does plone know how to deal with it? Is the client-side of the provided functionality, the out-of-the-box installed js-files and such, ready to deal with the ajax response of my specific portlet?

How does the clean and only js-ajax proposed way of updating a portlet work, especially on the client side?

Is there a way to update a portlet without javascript and/or kss, as a fall-back solution?

I am working with a clean Plone 4.2.4 install with buildout on a centos platform, python 2.7.3.

Maybe some advice, especially on what goes on and how exactly on the client side of the portlet update functionality could help people at a similar level of knowledge like me. The portlet related code on the server side is documented enough to understand how the portlet machiney works, but I can not find enough information for me to understand whats going on exactly in an portlet update refresh roundtrip, and how to "snap into" the provided machinery with my own portlet command set.